I want to create an animation that substitutes one image for another, simulating an avertisement but I don't know how
(What I've tried is based on another post here)
I want 'kenny.jpg' to be the starter image, after three seconds, it changes to 'kyle.png', after three seconds, to 'cartman.jpg', after three seconds to 'stan.jpg'and finally after those three seconds to kenny again, on loop with 1.5s fade between each image
So far, this is my code:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Prueba Animaciones</title>
        <style>
            .images {
                    overflow: hidden;
                    animation: fade 1.5s infinite alternate;
                            }
            @keyframes fade {
               0% {opacity: 1;}
               25% {opacity: 1;} 
               50% {opacity: 0;}
               75% {opacity: 0;}
            }
        </style>
    </head>
<body>
<div class="images">
<img src="kenny.jpg">
<img src="kyle.png">
<img src="cartman.jpg">
<img src="stan.png">
</div>
</body>
</html>


I posted an answer before showing a working demo.. but I forgot to take account for the fadein/fadeout .. so I just deleted it. Anyway you may use animation-delay on each picture so that each one will start the same animation after 3s*i. To account for the delay you need to change the % of your keyframes when the opacity is set to 1
